# Powershell compatible regex flavors

Tags: regex, powershell

I am testing in Powershell, some regex that I get from a program written in another language.

But the regex arent working properly, I know that depending on the regex flavor like PCRE,POSIX. The regex is interpreted in different way.

My question is what are the compatible regex Flavors for powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct flavor is .Net regex, but in online testers like [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com) that don't have it, I use PCRE and it seems to work fairly well.

Other issues you may run into are whether or not you need to escape certain characters in the string for powershell (irrespective of characters that need to be escaped for the regex engine).